# Get a list of values from 3D array using 2D index array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 3D array that looks like this:

```
edges = round(rand(20,20,20)));
```

I then create a random list of indices as follows:

```
indices = floor(rand(10000,3)*(19))+1;
```

So if I try to use the first row of the indices 2D array to access an element in the `edges` array, I do:

```
>>> edges(indices(1,1),indices(1,2),indices(1,3))
>>> ans = 1
```

I figured, if I wanted to get the value of `edges` at all of the index positions, I could do

```
>>> edges(indices)
```

but that returns an `10000` by `3` matrix. I would expect a `10000` by `1` matrix with values of `edges` at positions specified by each row of `indices`. What is going on here, and is there a way to get the values I want without using any `for` loops?

Comment: read about `sub2ind` and `ind2sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use a single index into `edges` instead of 3:

```
edges = round(rand(20,20,20));
indices = floor(rand(10000,1)*(20^3-1))+1;
edges(indices)
```

You should use `randi()` instead of `round(rand())` as well, because `round(5*rand())+1` will give you fewer 1s and 6s than 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s.

```
edges = randi(2,20,20,20)-1;
indices = randi(20^3,10000,1);
edges(indices)
```